# Java certificate unknown when using valid certificate

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I have been asking a lot of questions on here recently, and it turns out it was all due to one thing, the SSL certificate I had downloaded from my website did not have the private key with it, so I converted the certificate and key to PKCS12 , a .pfx file, using the SAME key password as the keystore password, imported it with keytool into a .jks file and I set the System Property in my main class. This certificate is definitely valid as it comes from Comodo Positive SSL. But when I try and connect and send data, I continuously get these errors.

**Errors**
http://pastebin.com/UWbjJLjn

Does anybody have any thoughts on why this is occuring. My client log says that my certificate IS valid if that helps.

**Server**

```
private static SSLSocket socket;

public PacketHandler() {
        initListen();
}


private void initListen() {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/Users/181095/ting_keystore.jks");

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
    try {


        SSLServerSocketFactory sf = (SSLServerSocketFactory)SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();

        SSLServerSocket serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket)sf.createServerSocket(Ting.port);



        System.out.println("Server Started and listening to the port "
                + Ting.port);

        // Server is running always. This is done using this while(true)
        // loop
        while (true) {

            // Reading the message from the client
            socket = (SSLSocket)serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(socket.getSupportedProtocols()));
             System.out.print( Arrays.toString(sf.getSupportedCipherSuites()));


            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String input = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message received from client is " + input);
            /*if(PacketReader.isPacket(input)){
                if(PacketReader.shouldSendDataBack(input)){

                }
            }*/
            /*
             * 
             * if client has data waiting or client has new data
             * request new data.
             * else, wait 5 seconds and repeat
             * 
             * 
             */



            // Sending the response back to the client.
            /*OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
            bw.write("");*/

            //TODO Implement method to send this data to client storage      data.

            //bw.flush();
        }
    //Check for exceptions and try to close the socket.
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
public static void Message(String args) {

    System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");

    try
    {
        String host = "localhost";
        int port = 3498;
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);


        SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(address, port);
      System.out.print(Arrays.toString(socket.getSupportedProtocols()));




        //Send the message to the server
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

        String number = "Hello from the other side!";

        String sendMessage = number + "\n";
        bw.write(args);
        bw.flush();
        System.out.println("Message sent to the server : "+sendMessage);

        //Get the return message from the server

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        //Closing the socket
        try
        {
            socket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print(e.getCause());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the error the certificate cannot be validated as no valI'd certificate path can be found. You need to verify that all required certificated in the chain are available (either in the .jks or in the general jeystore). I would suggest to use 'Portecle' as a very user friendly for viewing the contents if the key stores.

Comment: I have done that but what exactly should it look like?